# what does 見てできる mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Can this phrase be broken down into `見る`　and `出来る`?

If so, does it simply mean "can see"? How is it different than the potential form of `見る` which is `見られる`?

**Edit:**

To add some context to this question, the phrase was seen in the title of a book - `見てできる臨床ケア図鑑`

Now, I've guessed that the phrase probably has something to do with one's capability of seeing, my follow up question is how is it different than using the other words such as `見える` and `見られる`?

Comment: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important

Comment: Broadly, it probably means that once you see something, you'll be able to do something else.  But without context, we can't say much more.  See @user3856370's link.

Comment: 見てできる can be broken down into 見る and できる. But it sounds strange, and never means 'you are able to see or look' (見ることができる). As Eirikr Utledi clearly stated, the meaning of this phrase is that once you see something, you'll be able to do something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

見てできる is just "[you] see and then [you] can do" or "[you] can do [it] after/by seeing [it]", not "can see". If you know the basic function of the te-form, this should be straightforward. It never means 見られる/見える, and it has nothing to do with one's seeing ability.

見てできる modifies 臨床ケア as a relative clause, so the very literal translation is "Pictorial book of clinical care which you see and then can do". The gist is that this book enables you to do patient management just by mimicking the pictures (i.e., you don't have to read a lot of text).

Comment: this might be a bit off topic but why is it できる though? Can I use する in this case? So it'd be 見てする

Comment: @Will する臨床ケア is grammatical but it makes little sense as a catchy book title. [できる is a popular phrase](https://book.impress.co.jp/category/series/dekiru/) for the title of a book for beginners.